# Backup a mongodb using a ssh

Tags: mongodb, ssh

Guys I am trying to backup a database.

First I connect to the server using a ssh tunel, then I execute the following command:

```
mongodump -d mydatabase -o ~/myfolder
```

and I get this message:

> connected to: 127.0.0.1 Thu Feb  6 18:00:56 DATABASE: mydatabase   to
>     /home/backups/myfolder/myfolder

As you can see, the mongodump is creating a folder inside a folder, but inside this folder I don't have any files, no json, no bson file.

Could someone, explain me how to make a backup on my server using ssh and the move the files to my local machine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is that all your output?
Also can you explain a little bit about the `ssh tunel` are you connecting via ssh ? are you creating a tunel with port forwarding and connect from your local machine? Please provide the ssh command.

Comment: Yes, I'm connected via ssh, and that's all that I got

Comment: it is strange, I don't get the same behavior, can you provide the version of mongodump ? `mongodump --version`. Also, are you sure that `mydatabase` has any data?

Comment: mongodump version 2.4.9 and Yes, I trying to back up the production DB

Comment: Would you like to dump the database from the mongod server running on your localhost or a remote host? If you want to dump the database from a mongod server running on a remote host, you need to use "--host <hostname>:<port>" option in mongodump, otherwise, it will dump the database from your localhost. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/ for more details about mongodump

Answer (score 13):

this is the command you are looking for.
this command will access your server database locally
 4321 is a port number which can be any port number in which you run your mongodb server **root@144.154.22.11** and this is your server ip.

**ssh -L 4321:localhost:27017 root@144.154.22.11 -f -N**

and after this

**mongodump --port 4321**

this command will make your mongodb dump.

Comment: After dumping, run the followings commands `ps aux | grep 'ssh -L 4321'` and `kill -9 PROCESS_ID` in order to find and kill the ssh port forwarding.